# Multiple loops not giving desired Result

Tags: android

I am working on a methods in which when I use a single loop with condition it checks both if and else conditions. But when I add more than one loop with condition it only checks else condition I do not know where is problem. please help me for that
here is my code

```html
 public void compareArray() {
        ArrayList<Boolean> subset = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j < (arrayBeef1.length); j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.size(); i++) {
                if ((arrayBeef1[j].equals(Items.get(i)))) {
                    subset.add(true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (subset != null) {
            if (arrayBeef1.length == subset.size()) {
                Intent nextClass = new Intent();
                nextClass.setClass(AddItem.this, BeefRecipes.class);
                startActivity(nextClass);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Un-Matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        for(int j = 0 ; j < (arrayBeef2.length) ; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.size(); i++) {
                if ((arrayBeef2[j].equals(Items.get(i)))) {
                    subset.add(true);
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
            if (subset != null) {
        if (arrayBeef2.length == subset.size()) {
            Intent nextClass = new Intent();
            nextClass.setClass(AddItem.this, BeefRecipes.class);
            startActivity(nextClass);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Un-Matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

where Item array is dynamic array which is populated through spinner and beefArray1 and two are

```html
String[] arrayBeef1 = { "carrot","ginger",
            "onion","beef","unsalted butter"};
    String[] arrayBeef2 = { "garlic","olive oil", "onion",
            "Dijon mustard","beef","salt","carrot","rosemary"};
```

and Items arraList is produced with similar items
please help what should I do with this method

Comment: What are you trying to check in this code?

Comment: I want to jump on next activity if any of the above condtion is satisfied but it checks only first condition means if statement

Comment: Why do u think the second if is not checked? Maybe it's checked but the condition is evaluated to false? ( + I don't think your code is doing what you want it to do)

Comment: no sir condition is true because I check it one by one 
sir can you suggest me any idea ?

Comment: maybe you want to clear subset (subset.clear()) before testing Items against arrayBeef2?